# Delphi, copy content of a PNG image to another PNG image of different size

Tags: delphi, png

I want to copy the content of a PNG image to another bigger one. Source image is 16x16x32b, the destination is of the same format but two times broader. However the code below produces empty image. Changing COLOR_RGBALPHA to COLOR_RGB produces non transparent PNG. How to make it properly?

```
var
  png, pngsrc: TPngImage;
begin
  png := TPngImage.CreateBlank(COLOR_RGBALPHA, 8, 32, 16);
  pngsrc := TPngImage.Create;
  try
    pngsrc.LoadFromFile('c:\src.png');
    pngsrc.Draw(png.Canvas, Rect(16, 0, 32, 16));
    png.SaveToFile('c:\dst.png');
  finally
    png.Free;
    pngsrc.Free;
  end;
```

Comment: Why don't you just copy the files directly? Why do you use an intermediate PngImage and draw it?

Comment: or assign() instead of draw.

Comment: Its a simplified question, actually I need to put a source image to the place different from (0,0)

Comment: If the question doesn't state what you really want, how do you expect people to give you a satisfying answer? So why don't you edit the question and state what you really want? And how do you want to put a 16x16 image into a 16x16 image but *not* at the origin?

Comment: All right, done

Comment: I can't test this right now, but would `DrawUsingPixelInformation(Canvas, Point)` do a better job?

Comment: FWIW, try to load pngsrc first, and then do: `png := TPngImage.CreateBlank(pngsrc.Header.ColorType, pngsrc.Header.BitDepth, 32, 16);` just to be sure you have the right pixel info.

Comment: Tested it - no changes, dst.png is blank (src.png is definitely not blank)

Comment: I tried a little bit now. Seems that the alpha of the destination bitmap is 0 (transparent) for all pixels, but they have the correct colour. If you'd add a `png.RemoveTransparency;` before you saved it, you would see the image again, but on black, not on transparency. I didn't find a proper solution yet.

Comment: Yes, the same result can be obtained if you set COLOR_RGB instead of COLOR_RGBALPHA

Comment: Problem is that CGI routines like Draw() etc. do not set the top 8 bits, i.e. the Alpha channel, so the alpha values remain 0.

Comment: So TPngImage is useless?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copying a PNG with transparency into a larger PNG image can be achieved by transferring the alpha data as a separate step, as per the following code.

```
var
  png, pngsrc: TPngImage;
  X: Integer;
  Y: Integer;
  XOffset: Integer;
  YOffset: Integer;
  srcAlphaArray: pByteArray;
  destAlphaArray: pByteArray;
begin
  // Inspired by https://www.bverhue.nl/delphisvg/2016/09/26/save-bitmap-with-transparency-as-png-in-vcl/
  // Optional X and Y offsets to position source png into destination png
  XOffset := 16;
  YOffset := 0;
  png := TPngImage.CreateBlank(COLOR_RGBALPHA, 8, 32, 16);
  png.CreateAlpha;
  png.Canvas.CopyMode := cmSrcCopy;
  pngsrc := TPngImage.Create;
  try
    pngsrc.LoadFromFile('c:\src.png');
    pngsrc.Draw(png.Canvas, Rect(XOffset, YOffset, pngsrc.Width + XOffset, pngsrc.Height + YOffset));

    if pngsrc.TransparencyMode = ptmPartial then
    begin
      // Update destination png with tranparency data from original
      for Y := 0 to Pred(pngsrc.Height) do
      begin
        srcAlphaArray := pngsrc.AlphaScanline[Y];
        destAlphaArray := png.AlphaScanline[Y + YOffset];
        for X := 0 to Pred(pngsrc.Width) do
        begin
          destAlphaArray^[X + XOffset] := srcAlphaArray^[X];
        end;
      end;
    end;

    png.SaveToFile('c:\dst.png');
  finally
    png.Free;
    pngsrc.Free;
  end;
end;
```